# What does "entry" mean in this Java code?

Tags: java, rest

In my lecture, there is a sample code about building a REST web service with Java.

```
GET http://localhost/addressbook/Mr%20Suit

public Entry getEntry(String personName) {
    for (Entry entry : addressBook) {
        if (personName.equals(entry.getName())) {
            return entry;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I don't understand what does the `entry` mean in this code?

Comment: Could it be a class ? Like how `String` is ?

Comment: Check [Using Enhanced For-Loops with Your Classes](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have an addressBook, then it will have

1. Name of the person
2. Address
3. Contact info

so each line will look like

1. name1     address1     contact1
2. name2     address2     contact2
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
   10.name10    address10    contact10

**So basically each line is an Entry(the one given in the code)**

Now each **Entry** contains name, address, contact number.

The code just takes **personName** as parameter, matches it against all the entries in the addressbook.
If a match is found then the complete line of the addressbook is returned.
That is the complete entry is returned.

*Basically you are matching each line of the addressBook to get a particular name, and when the name is matched you pick the line containing the name and other details and return it.*

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you have a `list` of `addressBook`, from there you are trying to get an object of `Entry` which matches the `personName` passed as an argument. Entry is the object whose name is matching with the `personName` passed

Comment: Then what does "Entry entry : addressBook" mean? Since the code is to get http://localhost/addressbook/Mr%20Suit. Then addressbook is one entry, while Mr Suit under addressbook is another entry, is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

`entry` is the name of the `Entry` object.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand what does the "entry" mean in this code?

`entry` is name of the loop variable for the `for` loop.  Each element of the `addressbook` array or iterable is assigned to it, and the loop body is executed ...

Answer (score 0):

Entry is a class that your instructor made. From my knowledge there is not a class in the Java standard language that is called "Entry".

I am assuming the class looks something like:

```
public class Entry {

private String name;

public Entry(String name){

    this.name = name;
}

String getName(){
   return name;
}

}
```

Hope this helps...

Now in your loop:

```
for (Entry entry : addressBook) {
        if (personName.equals(entry.getName())) {
            return entry;
        }
    }
```

entry is of Entry class. You could have name it:

```
for (Entry myChoice : addressBook) {
        if (personName.equals(myChoice.getName())) {
            return myChoice;
        }
    }
```

It doesn't matter what you name it but its very important it makes sense and by convention

> Entry entry

is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Entry` is a class, a class that holds data (a bean) most probably.

What your method is doing is searching through an object called `addressBook`, this is probably a `List` that holds all the entries. When it finds an `Entry` with the same name as the `String` passed through the parameters then it will return that specific `Entry` object.